# Is fire-making allowed?

Tags: vinaya, sangha, rules

Fire ceremonies are likely categorized as ‘rites and rituals’, but is/was the basic usage of fire for warmth prohibited by monastic rules?

Comment: I haven’t read of any such rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See pages 564 and 565 of [The Pāṭimokkha Rules
Translated & Explained](https://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/Ebooks/BMC1&2_220701.pdf) by Ṭhānissaro Bhikkhu

> > Should any bhikkhu who is not ill, seeking to warm
> > himself, kindle a fire or have one kindled—unless there is
> > a suitable reason—it is to be confessed.

The explanation includes,

> There is no offense if one lights a fire or has one lit for purposes other
> than warming oneself.

and

> In addition, there is no offense in warming oneself at raked-out coals
> or at a fire lit by someone else (not at one’s request).

and

> The purpose of this rule is suggested by AN 5:219, which lists the
> five disadvantages of sitting around a fire: It is bad for one’s eyes, bad for
> one’s skin, bad for one’s strength, and (most importantly, in this context)
> groups tend to form (that can turn into factions), and they spend their
> time in animal talk.
>
> Summary: Lighting a fire to warm oneself—or having it lit—when one
> does not need the warmth for one’s health is a pācittiya offense

You're also not allowed to light a fire on soil -- because that's counted as (and covered by the rule against) digging soil.